Logic apps: Using expression to remove \n
I have a logic app that sends data to another logic app.

the data sent will always have \n\n at the end.
how do i clean it. i've tried using the replace function but it doesnt work.
replace(triggerBody()?['command'],'\n','')



Using the following expression cleans the string recieved from the HTTP post request above.
to reference \n the decodeUriComponent function is used where \n is represented as %0A
replace(triggerBody()?['command'], decodeUriComponent('%0A'), '')


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
